# Collect data from user: custom email

Tags: 2007, workflow

Within my workflow I am using the 'Collect Data from user'. I want to send a custom email (by turning of alerts on the Task list) and using the Send Email action.

My problem is I want to send a link with the task to approve in an email to the user the task has been assigned to (approver). But the action ''Collect Data from user' pauses until the task is edited which won't happen because I haven't sent the details to the approver via an email!

Is there any way to get around this? Or get a reference from a newly created task back to item that created it from the 'Collect Data from user' action?

Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out how to do this at last.

Create another workflow to on the Tasks list when an item is created.

Reference the item that created this task by using the Item ID to match the WOrkflow Item ID.

Now you can send custom emails with this action for one click approval.... :D

Answer (score 0):

If the email just says something like "Approval needed on an item..." then how about sending the email first, then add your "Collect data" action? You'd be able to do this with one workflow, instead of two.

Comment: I need to add the ID of the task in the email which only gets created after the collect data action.

Comment: im using the task ID to send the approver a direct link of the task.