# collect data from user in workflow custom email - link to approve

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have the exactly same question as mentioned here : [Collect Data from User in Workflow - custom email - collect data URL creation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23133/collect-data-from-user-in-workflow-custom-email-collect-data-url-creation?rq=1&newreg=e03d1a988e9b47d8ab3686597cdb38bf)

I want to send a custom **email** but including the link to the form that will ask the data I want to collect. I don't understand very well the answer on the topic i shared the link, even in this topic that is similar : [Collect data from user: custom email](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3325/collect-data-from-user-custom-email?rq=1)

Can someone give a clear picture? I understand I need to create another workflow, but why and how I find the link to the form and then is the data really collected?

Answer (score 1):

After you created the collect data from a user action in SharePoint Designer, on the ribbon go back to the main setting corresponding to that workflow ( where it has workflow setting/information/start options). In this area there should be a Form under "Forms" corresponding to your task ( named whatever you named your task) if you click on that form you can customize it anyway you want and this is where your data fields are. Make sure you save and publish and this is the form that will be sent as an email each time the workflow is initiated.

Another option would be right underneath the action to collect data from user you can put another action to send an email. You can customize this email and include the links to your task by clicking on the "add or change lookup" button. Once clicked for Data Source you want to select "association: task list" then for field from source whatever task you are looking For. For direct links you should use the same "add or change lookup" button but for data source choose current items and field from source you will see there are various things such as names and urls pertaining to your item that you may choose.